# How use variable as key in Twig's for loop?

Tags: php, twig

I'm trying to loop over Php variables which holds arrays. I want to pass variable in the key of the for loop var

It's suppose to look like that :

```
       {% set fields_vars =["dogs","cats","birds"] %}
       {% set foo = 123 %}

       <select  id="my_filter_1" class=" form-control filters_space filter">

                 // my_filter needs to be increment automatically

              {%  for fields_var  in fields_vars %}

                   <option >{{ fields_vars [ foo //pass twig variable as key//  ]}}</option>                        

              {% endfor %}
       </select>
```

I can't get the correct syntax for passing variables as keys - i've tried :

```
    <option >{{ fields_vars [ foo ]}}</option>        // Error            
    <option >{{ fields_vars [{{ foo }} ]}}</option>        // Error            
    <option >{{ fields_vars ['.'{{ foo }}'.' ]}}</option>        // Error
```

Thanks :)

Comment: What is the error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is `fields_vars [ foo ]`. I made you an example on a online ifddle

Fiddle: https://twigfiddle.com/tdau2h

```
{% set fields_vars =["dogs","cats","birds"] %}
{% set foo = 123 %}


{# value #}
{% if foo in fields_vars %}
  {{ foo }} is in array {{ fields_vars|join(', ') }}
{% else %}
  {{ foo }} is not in array {{ fields_vars|join(', ') }}
{% endif %}

{# key #}
{% if fields_vars[foo] is defined %}
   key {{ foo }} is in array {{ fields_vars|join(', ') }}
{% else %}
  key {{ foo }} is not in array {{ fields_vars|join(', ') }}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thanks! How can i set twig variables from array? - thanks to your solution i found another problem in my code....

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve ^^ what do you mean by `set twig variables from array` ?

Comment: I post another question for it - to complicated to explain in comments - thanks